# VBA Excel: Transfer individual sheet to Access

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to transfer an individual sheet (only 2 columns) in my Excel workbook to Access through VBA.  I would much prefer for the code to be written in Excel rather than Access, but the other way would work too.  Is there anyway to do this?

I have been searching for a way to do this but have yet to find anything beneficial.  I have a very limited amount of knowledge on this subject and lack other resources so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use ADO to connect to Access and then INSERT the records into a table